# AngularJS: How to add newly POST'ed item to the $scope without a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my controller:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.post('/node/api/stickies', $scope.formData)
          .then(function(data){
               $http.get('/node/api/stickies').success(function(data){
                   $scope.stickies = data;
                   })
           })
     });
```

right now its definitely not working. and I feel that the $http.get inside of the $http.post may be messing things up. but how else do I update the $scope.stickies without a page refresh?

Desired behavior: I have a list of items called stickies in an ul on my page. There is a post form above the stickies that adds new stickies to the db. I want my ul to add that newly posted stickie without me having to refresh the page.

```
 <form ng-submit = "createSticky()">
                    <input ng-model="formData.data" type="textarea" name="sticky_content" placeholder="add sticky text" required="true"/>
                    <input ng-model="formData.end" type="text" name="time_end" placeholder="expiration time (sec from current)" required="true"/>
                    <button type="submit" name="add_sticky" value="add a new stickie!">new sticky</button>
            </form>
            <div id = "stickies_list" class="row">
                    <ul id = "stickies"> 
                        <span class="sticky">
                                <li ng-repeat="stickie in stickies" ng-click="match(stickie)">
                                <h2>{{stickie.data}}</h2><br><br><br><br><br>
                                start time: <h10><mydate>{{stickie.start | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</mydate></h10><br>
                                stop time: <h10><mydate>{{stickie.end | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</mydate></h10><br><br>
                                Delete?: <input id="delete_checkbox" type="button" ng-click="deleteSticky(stickie.id)">
                                </li>
                        </span>
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: You don't need to refresh the page if you just update the scope variable properly it will reflect on template or controller

Comment: I added desired behavior. @CoderJohn how do I update the scope variable properly? is this something I would do inside of the inner http.post callback?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `$http` *service* by injecting it into your *controller*:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  ...
});
```

Comment: good catch. that was actually a typo. I have updated my question code though and the issue still stands.

Comment: You can add the new stickie to the $scope.stickies array after the post request resolves, which will prevent you having to hit the database a second time (with the get request). This will update your view after the post request completes.

Comment: so just $scope.stickies.push(data) in the .success part of the form post? that won't take into account server side adjustments I am making to the form data.

Comment: The data returned by your `$http.post` promise comes from the server, so it should be properly adjusted right? I would assume this post returns the newly created stickie item (same as the stickie I would receive if making a GET request).

Comment: so what goes in that callback to the $http.post? $http.post('/node/api/stickies').then(function(data){$scope.stickies = data}

Comment: You had it right the first time: `$http.post('/node/api/stickies').then(function(data){$scope.stickies.push(data)})`

Comment: You can console.log(data) if you are unsure what is being returned from the server.